# Changing total value using the lowest amount of coins, whilst excluding a specific coin, and return result as String

Tags: java, coin-change

I am facing an issue with one of my assignments, where a small part of the assignment is writing method for the below description:

> A method that takes two values; the value to exchange, and the coin type to exclude, and then return the minimum coins needed to exchange the for the total value, and return the output as a String. For example changeCalculator (555,50) may return "the coins to exchange are : 2 x 200p, 1 x 100p, 0x50, 2 x 20p, 1 x 10p, with a remainder of 5p".

I was able to write up a code, but the code I have written has System.out.print in the loop, and I am unable to make the code work whilst returning a string type, as I am using a loop.

All you need to know for my code, is at the start of the code class I have put and have already initialized the list of coins in the constructor:

```
private List<Integer> coinList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Here is my code below:

```
public void changeCalaculator (int totalCoinValue, int excludedCoinType)
{
    System.out.print("The coins exchanged are: ");
    for (int coin : coinList)
    {
        if (excludedCoinType == coin)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {

        System.out.print(totalCoinValue/coin + " x " + coin + "p, ");       
        totalCoinValue = totalCoinValue%coin;
        }   
    } 
    System.out.print(" with a reminader of " + totalCoinValue + "p"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For your method to return a `String` you firstly need to change your method declaration to show that the method actually does have a return type.
- Furthermore, instead of printing out the results, just build up a String along the way and return it after your method is finished. In the following example I used a `StringBuilder` for this task.
- Lastly, you were missing the output from the branch when your excluded coin type is added. (You don't need the `continue;` here, because there is nothing else to do in the loop, once the `if` branch is true)

Updated example:

```
public String multiCoinCalulator(int totalCoinValue, int excludedCoinType) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("The coins exchanged are: ");
    for (int coin : coinList) {
        if (excludedCoinType == coin) {
            sb.append(0 + " x " + coin + "p, ");
        } else {
            sb.append(totalCoinValue / coin + " x " + coin + "p, ");
            totalCoinValue = totalCoinValue % coin;
        }
    }
    sb.append(" with a remainder of " + totalCoinValue + "p");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: thank you, but is there some way i can System.out.print the sb string at the end of my code, before the return, just to check it works?

Comment: Of course you can. Or you save the returned String in a local String variable in the method where you call your `multiCoinCalculator`. E.g. `String result = multiCoinCalculator(562, 50);`. You can then do with that result whatever you want. E.g. `System.out.println(result)` if you want.

Comment: Thank mate! Really wasnt expecting a solution this quick.

Comment: No worries. If this cleared up all your questions, you could mark it as solved.

Comment: @ZaweeeZ new users should take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), after which you get the _Informed_ [bronze] badge.